# GUI tool to configure LDAP client

Tags: software-recommendation, ldap

I am using this [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) to configure LDAP client on Ubuntu. Now I am looking for a GUI tool to configure LDAP client on Ubuntu. My colleagues often complains that configuring LDAP client on Ubuntu is little difficult.

Is there any simple GUI tool for this?

Answer (score 12):

There is the [**LDAP Administration Tool** [image: Install lat]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lat), available from the repositories.

[image]

There is also the [**GQ LDAP Client** [image: Install gq]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gq), but it's a bit older and (I'm going to be blunt) not as good. :)

Comment: Today I'm testing Apache Directory Studio. Maybe someone can give it a shot: http://directory.apache.org/studio/

Comment: There are two reviews for this tool, and they are both 2/5 stars. Evidently it's very unstable.

Comment: JXplorer is a much better admin tool. (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jxplorer/)

Comment: this thing worked like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

### phpLDAPadmin

(Also known as PLA) is a web-based LDAP client. It provides easy, anywhere-accessible, multi-language administration for your LDAP server.

Its hierarchical tree-viewer and advanced search functionality make it intuitive to browse and administer your LDAP directory. Since it is a web application, this LDAP browser works on many platforms, making your LDAP server easily manageable from any location.

phpLDAPadmin is the perfect LDAP browser for the LDAP professional and novice alike. Its user base consists mostly of LDAP administration professionals.

Its best Features:

- LDAP tree browser
- Copy LDAP entries (even copy between different servers)
- Delete LDAP entries
- LDAP searches (both simple and advanced)
- LDIF import
- Manage user password hashes (supports sha, crypt, md5, blowfish, md5crypt)

Installation:

- Install apache

  ```
    sudo apt-get install apache2
  ```
- Install phpldapadmin

  ```
    sudo apt-get install phpldapadmin
  ```

Enter your browser and type : localhost/phpldapadmin

Connect to ldap server database

ITs a Great ldap manger

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

- [**Apache Directory Studio**](https://directory.apache.org/studio/downloads.html). You'll need to `sudo apt install default-jre`
- [**jxplorer**](http://www.jxplorer.org/) ([source](https://github.com/pegacat/jxplorer)). No update since 2018. Download .run from [here](http://jxplorer.org/downloads/users.html).
- [**phpldapadmin**](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). No update [since 2014](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpldapadmin/)
- [**gqclient**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gqclient/). No update since 2013.

For CLI [**`ldapsearch`**](https://cheat.sh/ldapsearch) from [`ldap-utils`](https://www.openldap.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP Administration tool you provided is to administer the actual LDAP database. It would be nice if there was an LDAP client such as the one available in OpenSuse so that Ubuntu can be easily configured to authenticate against the LDAP database. At the moment it's a real pain.

And also this [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) link doesn't seem to be very up-to-date. For Ubuntu 10.04 I would recommend this [blog](http://tuxnetworks.blogspot.com/2010/04/ldap-client-lucid-lynx.html).

Comment: Yes . You are right. i am looking for such a tool. The blog you have provided is a good one. But i am looking for a gui tool so that a beginner or normal user can configure the ldap client without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `ldap-auth-config` package on the Ubuntu client server.

It might have a few dependencies like

- `libldap`
- `ibnss-ldap`
- `libkrb53` (probably).

Once you install the package it is going to ask you for the LDAP login related details, for example, the URI and base domain. Provide them, and you should be well on your way towards getting the LDAP authentication right.

After you have LDAP packages installed, you can install `ldap-utils` and do a

```
ldapsearch -x
```

to verify that the client can bind to the LDAP master server.